# Unique Letter String (Leetcode)

Tags: java, substring

I was attempting to solve this question (https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-letter-string/description/), though I am having trouble understanding the problem statement.

The explanations says the below:

```
Input: "ABC"
Output: 10
Explanation: All possible substrings are: "A","B","C","AB","BC" and "ABC".
Evey substring is composed with only unique letters.
Sum of lengths of all substring is 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 = 10
```

What I don't understand is why is the substring **"AC"** missing in the all possible substrings.

Since several people have submitted the answer matching the above explanation without any questions, seems like my understand of substrings is wrong. Can anyone help with my understanding here?

Comment: Because `B` is between `A` and `C`, there is no substring of `"ABC"` where `A` and `C` are adjacent.

Comment: *"seems like my understand of substrings is wrong"* You seem to be confusing [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) with [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence). A **substring** is a *consecutive* sequence of characters from the original string, e.g. `AB` but not `AC`. A **subsequence** is a sequence that can be derived from the original string by deleting some or no characters without changing the order of the remaining characters, e.g. `AC` but not `CB`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! got it. @ElliottFrisch, Andreas please feel free to write this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. I was confusing subsequences with substrings.